# How to choose file in java?

Tags: java, filepath

I need to get file path for my java program during **runtime**. Is there any way to use default *dialog box* to choose a *single file* and get its full path and name?

Its just picking a file and get its path into a String object

Can you please provide the code for it or a tutorial?

PS: Windows OS

Comment: Is it a GUI program that you are looking for? what application are you trying to build?

Comment: If you are using swing [JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) or [FileDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html) if you are using javafx, [FileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html). The JFileChooser doc has an example of usage.

Comment: @shreyas-sarvothama Yes I'm looking for GUI File chooser

Comment: Then as @matt suggested, go for JFileChooser... I would recommend you to take a complete Java Tutorial. JavaFx if you are looking for GUI

Comment: If you don't have a preference for JavaFx or Swing, go for JavaFx. It is a modern GUI that Oracle actively developes these days (where Swing has not changed in more than 10 years).

Comment: Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is the example from the `JFileChooser` docs copy pasta with the parent sent to `null`.

```
public class PickAFile {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                "JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
                    chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't like the look of the JFileChooser try the `FileDialog`.

```
    FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog((Frame)null, "Select File to Open");
    dialog.setMode(FileDialog.LOAD);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    String file = dialog.getFile();
    dialog.dispose();
    System.out.println(file + " chosen.");
```

** The call to dispose is necessary to exit the program if this is an isolated call, or to prevent a memory leak if this is used in a larger application.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked!!

Comment: Is there a way to get the full Path? Figured it out thanks for post.  
        chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());

Comment: to add extention filter to FileDialog  you can go `FileDialog dialog =.... ; dialog.setFile("*.jpg;*.png;*.jpeg");`

Comment: You need to dispose of the dialog window after using it or the process hangs at termination:
`dialog.dispose()`

Comment: @ScrappyDev good catch. If it was a swing JDialog, I would use the setDefaultCloseOperation but the FileDialog is AWT so you're completely correct.